# Creating a twitter bot - Need help extracting a string

Tags: python, twitter

I'm pretty new to [python](/questions/tagged/python), and I don't know the best way to go about doing this. I've searched around, and I've solved most of my problems, but not this specific one.

I have a text file filled with random poems. For the purpose of testing, it's lorem ipsum. What I want to do is to extract a 140 character section out of this that is random. However, I only want it to include full words, so chop off the start and end up to the space.

eg.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent convallis nibh vitae ante dictum gravida. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus scelerisque accumsan ante, quis porttitor libero tincidunt vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ullamcorper ornare metus quis pulvinar. Nullam at magna mauris. Aenean nec arcu odio.

Using the bot, I might extract:

> tibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus scelerisque accumsan ante, quis porttitor liber

Which would then be truncated to:

> ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus scelerisque accumsan ante, quis porttitor

Essentially I'm trying to create a horse_ebooks like bot that takes random strings of random words from a file and posts them onto twitter. I've got the posting all sorted out, I just need the method of extracting the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 from random import random:
```

> text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent convallis nibh vitae ante dictum gravida. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus scelerisque accumsan ante, quis porttitor libero tincidunt vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ullamcorper ornare metus quis pulvinar. Nullam at magna mauris. Aenean nec arcu odio."""

```
poem_init = int(random()*(len(text)-140))
poem = text[poem_init:poem_init+140].split(" ")

if text.find(" "+ poem[0]) < 0:
    del poem[0]

if text.find(poem[-1] + " ") < 0 or text.find(poem[-1]) != len(text):
    del poem[-1]

poem = " ".join(poem)
print poem
```

Comment: I keep getting "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" on the `poem_init = int(random()*(len(text)-140))` line. I have no idea what this means, and I can't seem to fix it with my limited knowledge. I know what it's doing (generating an int that is a random number from the length of the text -140 so it doesnt go over) to use as a starting point, but it's not playing happy.

Comment: i think you are not importing just the random, so if you are using **import random** then you may use **poem_init = int(random.random()*(len(text)-140))**

Comment: Never mind, had to be `random.random()`. Thanks! **EDIT** Running it, it doesn't seem like the second half of  the code is working, it isn't truncating it on the spaces. **EDIT2** and with no modifications, its working now... What?

Comment: This is pretty much perfect! The only problem I'm having is the two if statements, sometimes I get chopped off words, and sometimes it starts with a space. I can't figure out why either.

Comment: you can use `poem = " ".join(poem).strip()`

Comment: What exactly does that do? It doesnt seem to do anything, and I still have the issue. Where the string is split, is it possible to just chop off the first and last bit of the split, regardless of whether or not its a full word? Aside from that, thanks a million! I've got the bot working (almost!) perfectly now =]

Comment: Never mind, got it! Turns out `poem = poem[1:] poem = poem[:-1]` works just fine, since it makes it start and end with full words. Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the first 140 characters of a poem.

```
final_poem = poem_string[:140]
```

Then to make things simple, you could find the location of the last space, and cut off everything from that space onward.

```
for i, char in enumerate(reversed(final_poem)):
    if char == ' ':
        chop = i + 1 # Remember indices start with 0
final_poem = final_poem[:-chop]
```

Probably not the most efficient code, but it gets the job done.

Comment: That looks like it could work!
I'll try and figure out how to start in a random position and cut the start off too.

Thanks!